# What is the actual implementation of OOPS concepts in ASP.Net Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I need to know how OOPS concepts can be implemented in an **ASP.Net application**. What i am looking for is an example to show how **OOPS Concepts** map with normal ASP.Net applications.

Eample:-**Inherits="Study._Default"** in aspx page is an example of inheritance.

Comment: All elements of OOP are *trivially* visible there... have you looked for any particular things?

Comment: no.Where i can find exapmles of polymorphism,abstract,encapsulation etc..i need to know actual implementation of OOPS.

Comment: have you looked first? it should be **trivial** to find polymorphism (any virtual method)? or an abstract class (or an interface)? Don't get me wrong: it would be easy for me to provide specific examples here, but: can you at least try to look first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOP is applied everywhere in ASP.NET related files (code behind files) and whole solution (MVC, 3-tiers, n-tiers, MVP or SOA...).

Please refer these links in case you want a deeply sight:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/c-asp-net-developers/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2011/12/08/object-oriented-programming-guidebook-in-asp-net-oop.aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eecabral/OOPSand.NET211102005075520AM/OOPSand.NET2.aspx